# How to select the first 100 rows from datatable and convert it to IEnumerable selectlistitem in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable filled from a text file and I want to select only top 10 rows from it and convert them to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` source.

Here is my code:

```
using (Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(path))
{
     parser.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
     parser.SetDelimiters(delimiter);
     parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

     bool firstLine = true;

     while (!parser.EndOfData)
     {
         //Processing row
         string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

         // get the column headers
         if (firstLine)
         {
             foreach (var val in fields)
             {
                 dt.Columns.Add(val);
             }

             firstLine = false;
             continue;
          }

          dt.Rows.Add(fields);
     }
 }
```

How do I do that?

Comment: A text file is not a database.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to read a csv file. Try using a library like CsvHelper for this https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ it makes like easier and can map to a type easily.

Comment: And you can use `File.ReadLines(path).Take(10).ToArray()` to only read the first 10 lines, then parse them.

Comment: @ScottG that's a pretty broad assumption perhaps you should ask the OP what the `Delimiter` Is

Comment: @MethodMan you can read any sort of delimited file with that by setting the delimiter you are looking for https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#configuration-delimiter

Comment: or he could write 4 to  6 lines of code to create his/her own parser many ways to skin this cat..

Comment: So basically, you show us the code that creates the datatable (is it working as expected?) and want an answer that selects rows from this table `dt`? If thats the case, please describe your previous work to find a solution and why it's not working.